# Removing an item from a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

How do I remove items from, or add items to, a select box? I'm running jQuery, should that make the task easier. Below is an example select box.

```
<select name="selectBox" id="selectBox">
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    <option value="option4">option4</option>    
</select>
```

Answer (score 501, accepted):

Remove an option:

```js
$("#selectBox option[value='option1']").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selectBox" id="selectBox">
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option> 
</select>
```

Add an option:

```js
$("#selectBox").append('<option value="option5">option5</option>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selectBox" id="selectBox">
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: If you need to remove an option and select another: $('#selectBox').val('option2').find('option[value="option1"]').remove();

Comment: Honestly, I think the way select boxes are manipulated via javascript is one of the most confusing things ever, even when you have a reasonably good understanding of selectors and the DOM.

Answer (score 82):

You can delete the selected item with this:

```
$("#selectBox option:selected").remove();
```

This is useful if you have a list and not a dropdown.

Comment: It is removing everything for me... Wait I am using Select with multiple attribute. How I can remove it from multiple select ?

Answer (score 28):

```
window.onload = function ()
{   
    var select = document.getElementById('selectBox');
    var delButton = document.getElementById('delete');

    function remove()
    {
        value = select.selectedIndex;
        select.removeChild(select[value]);
    }

    delButton.onclick = remove;    
}
```

To add the item I would create second select box and:

```
var select2 = document.getElementById('selectBox2');
var addSelect = document.getElementById('addSelect');

function add()
{
    value1 = select2.selectedIndex;
    select.appendChild(select2[value1]);    
}

addSelect.onclick = add;
```

Not jQuery though.

Comment: @JBeckton: looking back at this written 4 years ago I laugh at myself and you are right :)

Answer (score 25):

To Remove an Item

```
$("select#mySelect option[value='option1']").remove();
```

To Add an item

```
$("#mySelect").append('<option value="option1">Option</option>');
```

To Check for an option

```
$('#yourSelect option[value=yourValue]').length > 0;
```

To remove a selected option

```
$('#mySelect :selected').remove();
```

Answer (score 20):

This should do it:

```
$('#selectBox').empty();
```

Answer (score 18):

I find the jQuery [select box manipulation plugin](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/) useful for this type of thing.

You can easily remove an item by index, value, or regex.

```
removeOption(index/value/regex/array[, selectedOnly])

Remove an option by
- index: $("#myselect2").removeOption(0);
- value: $("#myselect").removeOption("Value");
- regular expression: $("#myselect").removeOption(/^val/i);
- array $("#myselect").removeOption(["myselect_1", "myselect_2"]);
```

To remove all options, you can do `$("#myselect").removeOption(/./);`.

Comment: -1 because this can be done w/o a plugin using jQuery and basic programming.

Comment: ᕀ1 why reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 9):

Adding/Removing value dynamically without hard-code:

// remove value from select dynamically

```
$("#id-select option[value='" + dynamicVal + "']").remove();
```

// Add dynamic value to select

```
$("#id-select").append('<option value="' + dynamicVal + '">' + dynamicVal + '</option>');
```

Answer (score 8):

I found two pages that seem helpful, it's written for ASP.Net, but the same stuff should apply:

1. [How to add/remove items from a dropdown list using jQuery](http://codeleacher.wordpress.com/2008/12/09/how-to-addremove-items-from-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery/)
2. [jQuery selector expressions](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)

Answer (score 5):

The following links will be helpful-

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 5):

Just to augment this for anyone looking, you are also able to just:

```
$("#selectBox option[value='option1']").hide();
```

and

```
$("#selectBox option[value='option1']").show();
```

Comment: I think this varies depends on browser. It might just disable that particular option.

Comment: I don't recommend this method, as it is browser specific.

Comment: This is an old post but I would like to comment on this. Although this is a very nice way to deal with select option, it is not recommended because IE doesn't support it

Answer (score 4):

#### JavaScript

```js
function removeOptionsByValue(selectBox, value)
{
  for (var i = selectBox.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (selectBox[i].value == value) {
      selectBox.remove(i);
    }
  }
}

function addOption(selectBox, text, value, selected)
{
  selectBox.add(new Option(text, value || '', false, selected || false));
}

var selectBox = document.getElementById('selectBox');

removeOptionsByValue(selectBox, 'option3');
addOption(selectBox, 'option5', 'option5', true);
```

```html
<select name="selectBox" id="selectBox">
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    <option value="option4">option4</option> 
</select>
```

#### jQuery

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    remove_options: function(value) {
      return this.each(function() {
        $('> option', this)
          .filter(function() {
            return this.value == value;
          })
          .remove();
      });
    },
    add_option: function(text, value, selected) {
      return this.each(function() {
        $(this).append(new Option(text, value || '', false, selected || false));
      });
    }
  });
});

jQuery(function($) {
  $('#selectBox')
    .remove_options('option3')
    .add_option('option5', 'option5', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selectBox" id="selectBox">
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    <option value="option4">option4</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove the first option from a select, with no ID, only a class, so I used this code successfully:

```
$('select.validation').find('option:first').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
   

$("#selectBox option[value='option1']").remove();
$("#selectBox").append('<option value="option1">Option</option>');
```

```html
 when you want to totally remove and add option from select box then you can use this code

<select name="selectBox" id="selectBox">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option>    
</select>
```

```js
 $("#selectBox option[value='option1']").hide();
 $("#selectBox option[value='option1']").show();
```

```html
sometime we need to hide and show option from select box , but not remove then you can use this code


<select name="selectBox" id="selectBox">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option>    
</select>
```

```js
$('#selectBox :selected').remove();
$("#selectBox option:selected").remove();
```

```html
sometime need to remove selected option from select box then

<select name="selectBox" id="selectBox">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option>    
</select>
```

```js
('#selectBox').empty();
```

```html
when you need to remove all option then this code

<select name="selectBox" id="selectBox">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option>    
</select>
```

```js
$('#selectBox').find('option:first').remove();
$('#selectBox').find('option:last').remove();
```

```html
when need to first option or last then this code

<select name="selectBox" id="selectBox">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option>    
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to suggest another way to add an `option`.
Instead of setting the `value` and `text` as a string one can also do:

```
var option = $('<option/>')
                  .val('option5')
                  .text('option5');

$('#selectBox').append(option);
```

This is a less error-prone solution when adding options' values and texts dynamically.

Comment: I am not the downvoter but it appears that you answered OP halfway with how to add an option, but not how to remove an option.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody need  delete **ALL** options inside a select, i did a litle function.

I hope you find it useful

```
var removeAllOptionsSelect = function(element_class_or_id){
    var element = $(element_class_or_id+" option");
    $.each(element,function(i,v){
        value = v.value;
        $(element_class_or_id+" option[value="+value+"]").remove(); 
    })
}
```

Only have to run

```
removeAllOptionsSelect("#contenedor_modelos");
```

Comment: Isn't the result equal to `$('#contenedor_modelos').empty();` ? Nice to see some action though :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone else will need one elementary way to clear the select:

```
document.getElementById(SELECT_ID).innerHTML = "";
```