# is there a jquery solution for removing an item from a select dropdown by display text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, drop-down-menu

I see a number of examples of removing an item from a select dropdown by the items value ( such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375508/removing-an-item-from-a-select-box) ) but is there a way to remove an item from a select dropdown if all I know is the display text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#Select>option:contains(yourtext)").remove();
```

Tested it locally and it works. The exact snippet of code relevant to me was:

```
<select id="FundManager1" class="FundManagerSelect">
    <option>Fund Manager 1</option>
    <option>Fund Manager 2</option>
    <option>Fund Manager 3</option>
</select>
```

Then the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($("#FundManager1>option").length);  //alerts '3'
    $("#FundManager1>option:contains(1)").remove();
    alert($("#FundManager1>option").length);  //alerts '2'
});
```

You could always put it in a function:

```
function RemoveOption(SelectId, TextVal) {
    $("#" + SelectId + ">option:contains(" + TextVal + ")").remove();
}

RemoveOption("FundManager1", "1");
```

**Further Edit for Class Selector Question:**

For class selector, replace the '#' with a '.' as you would expect:

```
$(".YourSelectClass>option:contains(yourtext)").remove();
```

And as this is just a select, you can speed it up by combining with an element selector:

```
$("select.YourSelectClass>option:contains(yourtext)").remove();
```

Comment: Pretty sure you want quotes around yourtext: `'yourtext'`, unless `yourtext` is a variable, which you should probably make clear.

Comment: @Dominic Rodger. Nope it works as is. Tried it with spaces too.

Comment: is there anyway to do this for as a class selector so i can remove an item from multiple selects at once?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you could iterate over them:

```
$('select option').each(function()
{
    if ($(this).text() == 'something')
    {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

**Edit:** James Wisman's answer is more concise, but this might be easier if the option has awkward characters in it that would otherwise interfere with the selector syntax.

Comment: +1 - Agreed. I've not encoutered too many of these however :-)

Comment: is there anyway to do this as a class selector so it applies to multiple selects with one set of code?