# remove specific items from dropdown list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multi select dropdown list.  I can get the array of selected values using:

`selectedItems = $("#myList").val(); // works`.

Now, how can I remove the selected items from the dropdown list?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$("#myList option:selected").remove();
```

[will work](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/kwVhD/).

---

*Edit: I misunderstood the comment, but I will leave it as an example for removing certain elements in general.*
If you want to remove the elements based on the value in the array, you have to loop over the array:

```
var $list = $("#myList"),
    toRemove = $();

for(var i = selectedItems.length; i--;) {
   toRemove = toRemove.add($list.find('option[value="' + selectedItems[i] + '"]'));
}
toRemove.remove();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/kwVhD/3/)

Comment: thanks, say I already have a variable pointing to my list: var myList = $("#myList"); how do I use this variable to do what you suggested?

Comment: Actually, I want to use the first way you suggested.  My only question was that I already have a variable pointing to the select element; so i don't know how to apply the "option:selected" to it.

Comment: @john: Oh sorry, I misunderstood that. You can use `find` then: `myList.find('option:selected').remove()`.

Comment: @john: Or `children`: `myList.children('option:selected').remove()`

Answer (score 2):

This could help you:- [Remove Selected Option using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375508/removing-an-item-from-a-select-box)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("[Id$='ddlShowRun'] option:selected").remove();
```