# getting text value , regex or DOM method?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following block

```
<span id="title"><select id="optionType"><option>choose option</option><option> hello</option><option>how are you</option></select></span>
```

I want to remove the first option and need to get the all other options in new line, only the option text with out any tags . Is regular expression is the best one to use, or is thire any other better method to retrieve text in new line ? I tried the following but it can fail somtimes

```
Description= $('title').innerHTML;
var tmp = Description;

tmp = tmp.replace("--Choose an option--</option>",""); // remove first option
tmp = tmp.replace(/<\/option><option>/g, "<\/option>\n<\/option>"); 
tmp = tmp.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g,""); 
tmp = tmp.replace(/\n/g, "\n"); 
tmp = tmp.replace(/^[\s]*/gm, '');

return tmp;
```

Comment: since we're in Javascript (and therefore presumably in a browser), this would be much easier to do using standard DOM methods than with Regex.

Comment: Try to use a more descriptive title and format your post correctly. This will increase the answer rate and quality.

Comment: @Spudley : can u help me in starting with DOM methods ? does it work in IE ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with the all other options. Could you provide us an exemple of the desired result ?

Comment: Write a better question title please.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom

Answer (score 1):

Try with jQuery if possible instead of regex.

It would be something like

```
$("#optionType>option:first").remove() //to delete first option
$("#optionType>option") //list of other options
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(<option[^>]*?>([^<]+)<\/option>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just removing the option directly rather than fiddling with the HTML code?

Particularly easy, since you're using JQuery already:

```
$("#title option[value='--Choose an option--']").remove();
```

See also: [Removing an item from a select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375508/removing-an-item-from-a-select-box)