# dropdown with <option> blank, when trying to reset it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Maybe this sounds like a repeated question, but I've tried some solutions from other users but in my case nothing works.

I currently have a dropdown that displays a list of departments. I'm trying with the button to reset (clear dropdown), the dropdown has no option selected and only show the default option when nothing has been selected. this function when activated, generates this blank space. what am I doing wrong?

Thank you

```
<select   ng-model="select_deptos"  ng-options="item as item.NOMBRE_DPT for item in aDepartamentos track by item.DPTO" ng-change="fn_setSemestreFiltro('departamento')">
   <option value='' style="display:none;">Select</option>
</select>
<button ng-click="clear()">clear dropdown</button>

$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'depto.json'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.aDepartamentos=response.data;
})

$scope.clear=function(){
  $scope.select_deptos="";
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/BUTDCjanKb4xVIaIVMcp?p=preview

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932959/remove-values-from-select-list-based-on-condition

Comment: @TanDuong read my question well. I do not see relationship. I do not need to remove anything based on conditions. I just need to avoid creating a blank space. I ask you please remove this.

Comment: You can't use `style='display:none'` in option select box. This style will not affect. you just can use javascript to remove this option

Comment: @TanDuong I do not know how to solve it. That's why I put the question and please remove the duplicate, I do not see what you put in relation to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem:**

As mentioned by @Tan Duong, the style `display:none` does **not** work in `<option>`.

**Possible Solution:**

Use `$scope.select_deptos=null;` instead of `$scope.select_deptos="";`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ng-options you can use ng-repeat in option tag

```
<select   ng-model="select_deptos" ng-change="fn_setSemestreFiltro('departamento')">
   <option value='' >Select</option>
   <option ng-repeat='item in aDepartments' ng-value='item.DPTO'>{{item.DPTO}}</option>
</select>
<button ng-click="clear()">clear dropdown</button>

$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'depto.json'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.aDepartamentos=response.data;
})

$scope.clear=function(){
  $scope.select_deptos="";
}
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @Claies (Thanks for correcting)
According to angular documentation
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select
You should prefer using `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`. NgRepeat is not a good practice.
Prefer @terry.qiao 's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49642125/4005417

Comment: This is a terrible idea;  `ng-options` is designed specifically to be more flexible than `ng-repeat`.  The angular team specifically encourages people to use `ng-options` over `ng-repeat` whenever possible.

Comment: that depends on how you use it, their is no harm in using this way. it solves the problem, anyway it makes sense that using ng-options is better than ng-repeat

Comment: no, this hides the real problem.  `''` isn't a value in the list, so it shouldn't ever be what you set your model to.  `'' !== null`.... The real solution is to use `null` to represent no option selected.

Comment: hey. i am suing ur paytm package. i have done evrythng as u said. but wen i click the pay now button the page shows "transaction being processed" and then redirects me to a blank page like payment/api/status. why is it not taking me to paytm website?