# Delete an option tag with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this generated code:

```
<select class="generic-widget" id="auth_user_group_id" name="group_id">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="2">admin</option>
<option value="3">user</option>
<option value="1">guest</option>
</select>
```

I need use JS to delete the guest option and try to set the user option like default...

I tried with this JQuery code to delete the guest option, but something fails:

```
<script>
$('option').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('value') == '1') {
        $(this).remove();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Removing an item from a select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375508/removing-an-item-from-a-select-box)

Remove an option :

```
$("#auth_user_group_id option[value='1']").remove();
```

Comment: @Christian_Espinoza: You're saying that if you do nothing more than replace the code in your question with the above code, it suddenly works? That doesn't make sense,.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
$('#auth_user_group_id > option[value="1"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine as long as you run your code after the DOM is ready.

```
   // v----this handler will run after the DOM has loaded
$(function() {
    $('option').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('value') == '1') {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/TTUkS/

If your code placed at the top of the page, then it runs before the elements exist.

Comment: this way is more readable in my opinion: `if($(this).val() == '1') ...`

Comment: @Mic: I agree, but the point is that OP's code works correctly the way it's written. So the code itself doesn't need fixing, but *(likely)* it just needs to run after the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the value condition in the selector:

```
$('#auth_user_group_id option[value="1"]').remove();
```

Then you can use the `val` method to select an option:

```
$('#auth_user_group_id').val('3');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of an option item with:

```
$('option').each(function(){
if($(this).val() == '1') {
    $(this).remove();
    }
});
```