# Editing MVC MultiSelectList with jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I am making a multiselectlist in MVC. The html for it comes out like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple"  id="foo" name="foo">
<option value="15">Doctor of Medicine</option>
<option value="10">Doctor of Osteopathy</option>
...
```

I am trying to remove or hide an option using jquery:

```
$('#foo option:contains("' + removeThis + '")').remove();
```

or

```
$('#foo option:contains("' + removeThis + '")').hide();
```

The first does nothing. The second seems to add a display: none to the html, but it has no affect on the list item (you can still see it). Why not? How do I edit it?

Comment: A similar question can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375508/removing-an-item-from-a-select-box

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this on the front end? A better approach would be to edit the `IEnumerable<>` you provide to the `MultiSelectList` in the controller.

Comment: The question above has the same problem for me, that the changes don't seem to have any effect

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Doy...I've been working in a .cshtml page, I can just use razor there...will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved...turns out my late coworker was using this [multiselect widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/). I needed to use the UI to refresh it.

Moral of the story: fully research the existing code - it helps to know where an object comes from before trying to edit it.