# Delete dynamically created combo box option using javascript

Tags: javascript, combobox, buttonclick

- On click of **create** button, am creating a combo box option dynamically.
- My need is, on click of **delete** button, i have to delete the dynamically created option.

Combo box code:

```
<select id="connectionname" class="connectionname" onchange="display();" style="width:150px; height:23px;">
     <option>---Select---</option>
</select>
```

javascript to create/add options dynamically:

```
var NAME =dijit.byId("conname").getValue();
    var newValue = document.getElementById("connectionname").appendChild(document.createElement('option'));
    newValue.text = NAME;
    document.getElementById("connectionname").value = newValue.text;
```

Comment: have a look at this [Removing an item from a select box](http://stackoverflow.com/a/376112/2022859)

Comment: may i know why the question is down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var NAME =dijit.byId("conname").getValue();
var select=document.getElementById('connectionname');

for (i=0;i<select.length;  i++) {
   if (select.options[i].text==NAME) {
     select.remove(i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the removeChild method to remove dynamically added children

```
var elem =  document.getElementById("connectionname");
elem.removeChild(elem.childNodes[i]); // where i is index of child added last
```