# Multiple options in select that can only be selected once

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and have the following problem:

In HTML I have multiple select elements with the same list of options. (In this example 2.)
How can I make it that if you select 'Option 1' in the first select you can not select 'Option 1' in the second select element.
Also when you then select 'Option 2' in the first select you should be again  possible to select
'Option 1' in the second but not 'Option 2'.

This is how the html looks:

```
<select id="1">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>

<select id="2">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

This is what I found for the js: [Removing an item from a select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375508/removing-an-item-from-a-select-box)

I tried to use it to solve my problem but it didn't work.

Can you help me?
I'm sorry if this is very simple.

Comment: Can you post up how to tried to solve your problem?

Comment: What does it mean "it didn't work"? The linked answer works perfectly, so you need to show us your code and we can help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted. Hide the option and show it if other options are selected.

```js
$(function(){
$("#sel1").change(function(){
var selection=$(this).find(":selected").val();
$('#sel2 option').show();
var el=$('#sel2 option[value="'+selection+'"]').toggle();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel1">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>

<select id="sel2">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign id to each of the  tag, Create a Javascript function  that either adds or removes a particular option OnSelect.

The Example included should work.