# Remove one value from a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I want to remove one value from a dropdown list.

The code below works fine for the IE browser but it's not working for Chrome and Mozilla.

```
document.formName.propertyName.options[1].style.display="none";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing an item from a select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375508/removing-an-item-from-a-select-box)

Answer (score 0):

If dropdown list is < select > then use

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
x.remove(2);
```

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_select_remove2)