# $("select#mySelect option[value='option1']").remove() when "select#mySelect" is actually a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery

I've been looking at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048545/364088 which presents the following code.

```
$("select#mySelect option[value='option1']").remove()
```

That's useful but what can be done if you already have a variable initialized like this .

```
var mySel = $("select#mySelect");
```

How would you be able to incorporate that variable into the ".remove" example shown above ?

Something like this (but obviously not this)

```
mySel.("option[value='option1']").remove()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.find` to find descendants matching a particular selector:

```
mySel.find("option[value='option1']").remove()
```