# Remove some "options" from a option select list Html-javascript

Tags: javascript, html

a little help please,

I have this code, I would like to create a javascript function to delete the first three select options (50,55,60)
and keep only the last (65)
you can help me..... thanks

```
<select>              
 <option value="50" selected="selected">50</option>
 <option value="55">55</option>
 <option value="60">60</option>
 <option value="65">65</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what is your condition to delete the rows? first three rows or smaller than 65?

Comment: what did you try? what error did you encounter ?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375508/removing-an-item-from-a-select-box

Comment: I added my answer but you should have done some research before you asked here dude. You can easily get to the answer by doing a short research

Answer (score 0):

give the `<select>` an id , and check the function below:

```js
function filterSelect(){
var selectobject = document.getElementById("select_id"); 
for (var i=0;i<3;i++){
selectobject.remove(0);      
}       
}

filterSelect();
```

```html
<select id="select_id">              
         <option value="50" selected="selected">50</option>
         <option value="55">55</option>
         <option value="60">60</option>
         <option value="65">65</option>
        </select>
```

EDIT: if you want to add condition per option - add it inside the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
    

    var i = 0;
    while(i < 3){
        document.getElementById('selectId').removeChild(document.getElementById('selectId').getElementsByTagName('option')[0]);
        i++;
    }
```

```html
<select id="selectId">              
 <option value="50" selected="selected">50</option>
 <option value="55">55</option>
 <option value="60">60</option>
 <option value="65">65</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Adding some explanations would help others.