# How to hide product while i have already selected that product previously

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, reactjs

How to remove or hide product that i have already selected?

[image]

The product which is on select tag is coming from back-end.

Comment: Pls read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: selected product remove from the dropdown? when you comes again, the product is selected not shown? Is this your question?? please share complete question.

Comment: Please learn how to take screenshots, and don't take pictures of the screen with a camera.

Comment: @khadimhr yes sir... If i select one particular product then next time as you seen in picture ,, when i click on drop-down the same product is showing in the list of products... So my point is if someone select one particular product then next time.. the same product is not shown in the list... Hope you understand my question...

Comment: @ArchitGargi okay done ... Now give me some idea to solve my question...

Comment: @RiteshSingh Of course I would if I knew how to

Comment: You should show your code or how you implement it, that would be easier for supporters to help you.

Comment: @RiteshSingh , Dear go on this link, I hope you find a solution, how to hide, delete and shown products.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375508/removing-an-item-from-a-select-box

Answer (score 0):

You should filter your items that come from back end and then show them up in your list.
Create a field in your database as selected with default value of 0.
Update selected items to 1 or any other number then :

`const result = items.filter(item=> item.selected != 0 );`